# How to determine optimal thread stack size?

Tags: winapi, optimization, visual-c++, memory, stack

Actually, two sizes: initially committed and total reserved.

Do you use static or dynamic analysis? Which tools? Which techniques?

Comment: It looks like trial and error is all we will get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389219

Answer (score 2):

One technique is to paint your stack in main or the threads main with a known value and then on cleanup do a sweep from the stack limit until your known value is no longer found.

Your stack end will be defined as a symbol, generate a .map file to determine the stack limits and their symbol names.

It is discussed here: [How to determine maximum stack usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389219)

Comment: Thanks, this helps with "total reserved" part of the question.