# Converting Visual C/C++ inline assembly code to GCC equivalent code

Tags: c++, c, gcc, inline-assembly

I have found the following function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905316/how-can-i-find-out-how-much-space-is-left-on-stack-of-the-current-thread-using-v) and would like to get it to compile under MinGW:

```
size_t stackavail()
{
    static unsigned StackPtr;
    __asm mov [StackPtr],esp
    static MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    VirtualQuery((PVOID)StackPtr,&mbi,sizeof(mbi));
    return StackPtr-(unsigned)mbi.AllocationBase;
}
```

I tried to modify the code above and managed to compile and run it:

```
size_t stackavail()
{
    static unsigned StackPtr;

    __asm__ ("movl %%esp, %0\n\t" : "=r" (StackPtr) );
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    VirtualQuery((PVOID)StackPtr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
    return StackPtr-(unsigned)mbi.AllocationBase;
}
```

But I'm in doubt. Is it correct? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Looks correct for me, but you should try to avoid using `__asm__` for code that is intended to be portable.

Comment: Also, use of a static local makes this terribly unthreadsafe.

Comment: How about using the GCC builtin [`__builtin_frame_address()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) instead of inline assembly?  That's even portable to other architectures (such as x86-64).

Comment: Thank you all for the help! @AdamRosenfield: Great tip. It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the inline ASM, use

```
void* StackPtr = &StackPtr;
```