# Statically measuring the maximum stack memory required for a method in C

Tags: c, windows, gcc, arm, eabi

I have a large number of methods written in C spread across multiple files and all of them create local variables (mostly structure instances).
After compiling these with ARM EABI GCC compiler on Windows, I try to examine the .o object files using objdump.

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe -f -p -h -x -d -s -t test.o > test.txt
```

My question is:
**How do I calculate/retrieve the peak stack memory used by a method?**

None of the methods allocate any dynamically allocated memory using malloc. So, I hoped that this would be easier.

I need this because I need to compare the amount of memory used by each method when compiled with various optimization options. This is to check if any local memory optimization has been carried out.
I also understand that for some local variables, the compiler may use registers. However, I just need to know whatever is the maximum stack memory required by a method or if there is a way to calculate it.

Comment: Go through the disassembly and look for `push` and `sub sp, sp, #x` instructions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392173/12711

Comment: Yup, I think that's it! Strange that SO search didn't show up this result. Thanks Michael!

Comment: @Elroy: I've found that using Google to search SO generally gets me better results than SO's search.  Just drop a "site:stackoverflow.com" in the query.

Comment: Actually, the suggestions in that answer don't work.   `gcc` will lazily adjust the stack for some optimizations which will increase stack use at a benefit of performance.  Paradoxically, the higher optimization levels will load more locals in registers, reducing use.  So, even the `-fstack-usage` combined with a call graph is flawed; you need to know when `inlined` functions will have their locals removed from the stack.  See: [`-fconserve-stack`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

Comment: @artlessnoise Will check -fconserve-stack and check the difference. Thanks for the input!