# Best practices to determine stack usage in Ravenscar program

Tags: gcc, memory, ada

I am writing an Ada program using the Ravenscar subset (thus, I am aware of the number of running tasks at execution time). The code is compiled by gcc with the [`-fstack-check`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Stack-Overflow-Checking.html) switch enabled. This should cause the program raise a [STORAGE_ERROR](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-11-01.html) at runtime if any of my tasks exceed their stack.

Ada allows to set the upper limit for those (task-specific) stacks during the specification of the respective task like so:

```
pragma Storage_Size (Some_Value);
```

Now I was wondering what options I have to determine `Some_Value`. What I have heard of so far:

1. Do wild guesses until no STORAGE_ERROR is raised anymore. This is more or less what the OP suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389219/how-to-determine-maximum-stack-usage).
2. Feed the output of [`-fstack-usage`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Static-Stack-Usage-Analysis.html) in there.
3. Use some gnat specific extensions as outlined [here](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-93-gnat-dynamic-stack-analysis/) (how does this technically differ from item #2?).
4. Get a stack analyzer like [gnatstack](http://www.adacore.com/gnatstack) and let it do the work for you.

If I understand this correctly all the above techniques are *dynamic* (i.e. they require the program to run in order to work). Are static approaches also conceivable? E.g. by restricting myself further through some of Ada's high integrity options (such as [No_Recursion](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-H-4.html), what else?).

Perhaps any of you can name some best practices to tackle this problem and/or extend/comment on my (surely incomplete) list.

Bonus question: What is the default size of a task's stack when the above pragma is not specified? GCC's [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Stack-Overflow-Checking.html) only state this value depends on the runtime, without giving any concrete numbers.

Comment: Good question with good background research!

Comment: The default stack size is given in `System.Parameters.Default_Stack_Size` (file `s-parame.adb`).

Comment: @Simon : does that stack size relate to the environment task, declared tasks or all tasks? I ask because I came across a "set stack size" option that didn't affect the environment task - which was apparently not settable by any means with that specific compiler release, which also disobeyed ulimit settings. I worked around it by moving the entire program into a new task...

Comment: @Brian: a few lines below there’s `Default_Env_Stack_Size` (8 MB here, 5.2.0). Is there an environment _task_ if the program doesn’t call in the tasking runtime? (NB, what I’ve said is all desktop-related; I don’t know how AdaCore’s bare-board RTSs behave).

Answer (score 1):

You can generally check the stack space required by individual types with the `'Storage_Size` attribute (which counts in bits).

Once you have tabulated this (you may need to round it up to whole words/double words), you can add up how much stack space is used by each declarative region, and then walk through your calls to find the maximum stack usage.

Comment: Are you suggesting to do this manually? That sounds like a tedious endeavour... Is there perhaps any tool support for this?

Comment: I was literally suggesting that you do it manually.  I doubt that you can do it through static analysis unless you restrict yourself not to use recursion.  If you don't use recursion, it should be possible to write a small ASIS-based tool to do the job.