# Dynamic stack analysis and OS_Exit

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm trying to put Adacore's [Gem on dynamic stack size analysis](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-93-gnat-dynamic-stack-analysis/) into action on our project.

Our project uses a lot of different tasks and is killed using

```ada
procedure C_Exit (Status : Interfaces.C.int);
pragma Import (C, C_Exit, "exit");
```

This is rather equivalent to [GNAT's specific solution suggested by Simon Wright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28488161/2622010) which would lead to the MWE

```ada
with GNAT.OS_Lib;
procedure Main is

   task T is
      entry E (Size : Integer);
   end T;

   task body T is
   begin
      accept E (Size : Integer) do
         declare
            V : array (1 .. Size) of Integer := (others => 0);
         begin
            GNAT.OS_Lib.OS_Exit (0); -- this is the only difference to Adacores example
         end;
      end E;
   end T;

begin
   T.E (500_000);
end Main;
```

Binding this program with the `-u10` option (using Gnat 19.1 and 20.1) won't output any report (while it does when not exiting).

Is there a solution to get the report without changing "too much" my existent code base?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to *run the program to completion* in order to generate the report  (as mentioned in de Gem):

> The `-bargs -u10` switch causes `-u10` to be passed to the GNAT binder, which will allow up to ten tasks to be instrumented and will output their stack usage upon **program completion**.

When you call `OS_Exit` (or `C_Exit`), the program is mere aborted (instead of completed) as normal program termination / finalization is skipped:

```
   procedure OS_Exit (Status : Integer);
   pragma No_Return (OS_Exit);
   --  Exit to OS with given status code (program is terminated). Note that
   --  this is abrupt termination. All tasks are immediately terminated. There
   --  are no finalization or other Ada-specific cleanup actions performed. On
   --  systems with atexit handlers (such as Unix and Windows), atexit handlers
   --  are called.
```

I don't have any concrete solution here (maybe others have) other than to make sure *not* to call `OS_Exit` and to ensure that tasks are terminated properly. Below is the effect of `OS_Exit` on the code flow within the binder generated code:

**b__main.adb** (binder generated code, partial)

```
function main
  (argc : Integer;
   argv : System.Address;
   envp : System.Address)
   return Integer
is
  --  [...]
begin
   
   --  [...]

   Initialize_Stack_Analysis (10);  <<< Initialize stack analysis.
   Initialize (SEH'Address);
   adainit;
   Ada_Main_Program;                <<< Calls "your" Main program. ---+
   adafinal;                                                          |
   Output_Results;                  <<< Emit stack analysis report.   |
   Finalize;                                                          | 
   return (gnat_exit_status);                                    [ OS_Exit ] 
                                                                      |  
end; <----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've feared… So from the 4 options that were listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34765528/2622010), 1 is more or less what I've done on my project, 2 is not applicable as I'm not in ravenscar (and I'm using a lot of unbounded strings…), 3 is out per your answer. So I'm up to see if I have gnatstack available :)

Answer (score 1):

How about -

1. Fill stacks with known pattern
2. Let C_Exit call - if available - kill() to trigger coredump
3. Analyze stacks of coredump with debugger

Comment: How would you list all the tasks you have to abort then? I see no function for this in `Ada.Task_Identification`. Is there a solution to get this list dynamically to ensure no maintenance of the list is necessary?

Comment: What is an 'Abort-Program' exception? You can’t raise a specific exception in another task; you can abort the environment task using `Ada.Task_Identification.Environment_Task`, but note this [aborts the entire partition](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-C-7-1.html#p9) so there’s no way to take any further action.

Comment: @jesper-quorning You totally changed your answer so my comment and @simon-wright are now obsoletes: sad, you could have added your update to your message :) As of the current state of the answer, I must say I do not understand it. I do not need a coredump as I can simply stop on the `exit` function with gdb. But what would you do with the stack next? Do you mean analyze the stack sizes? If so, this wouldn't give me a max size but the current size which could be absolutely not correlated to the max size.

Comment: @Vser You are right. I should have made another answer. Still learning.

Comment: @Vser I would exercise the program and examine the stacks to see max usage. The parts still containing the pattern has not been used.