# Can one obtain actual stack size used by a thread in Java after some time of running?

Tags: java, stack-size

The idea would be to help determine the optimum stack size for a given Java application.

One thing that could be done with this information create a range-table of stack sizes which the threads could modify as they exit and which could be dumped periodically and at application exit.

**EDIT: This is in the context of running on customer machines with real workloads which I can't get profiler access to.**

EDIT2: In response to one answer, at (IIRC) 256Kb per thread, I have wondered for a while now how close that is to the reality of what's needed (I also wonder if this question might be not very relevant because *perhaps* stack space is allocated on demand).  We have an application server which is based on message passing and highly threaded and runs on everything from an ARM handheld to octo-core Linux, to midrange and mainframes - it would be good to have a feeling for where (and if) we can trade stack space for heap on systems with many message handlers.

There are some similar questions which are of interest, but they are native/os-specific:

- [How to determine maximum stack usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389219)
- [How to determine optimal thread stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177516/how-to-determine-optimal-thread-stack-size)

Comment: Just get yourself a 64-bit platform...

Comment: @Tom: Sure... and I'll just buy one for each of my customers along with 8 Gigs of RAM so I don't have to think about the software I design and write.

Answer (score 1):

Stack memory will be hard to obtain.

Best you can do, and quite easily, is JVM memory usage via [**`MemoryMXBean`**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html).

Answer (score -1):

Use JConsole-- you likely already have it:
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html
http://openjdk.java.net/tools/svc/jconsole/

Comment: I had thought about that (actually JVisualVM is better), and I use JProfiler... but this is in the context of running on customer machines with real workloads which I can't get profiler access to.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do that with the brand new [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) too.

Comment: Per my comment to Cuga's answer from May 5: "I had thought about that (actually JVisualVM is better), and I use JProfiler... but this is in the context of running on customer machines with real workloads which I can't get profiler access to."

Comment: Interesting - JVisualVM is bundled with Java 6 - I didn't know that it is also distributed via the web.  The plugins look quite useful.

Answer (score -3):

You may use the Runtime class to monitor the JVM memmory like this.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println((rt.freeMemory() / 1024) + "/" + (rt.maxMemory() / 1024) + " kB");
```

Or you may use JConsole, JVisualVM e JInfo.
You may get more information about these tools [Here:](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/)

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/

Comment: That doesn't tell us the stack size.

Comment: This way you only get the memory usage of the JVM instance or it can get only the memory usage of current thread too?