# Getting a program's stack size in Java

Tags: java, performance, profiling, stack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can one obtain actual stack size used by a thread in Java after some time of running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826206/can-one-obtain-actual-stack-size-used-by-a-thread-in-java-after-some-time-of-run)

Is there a way programatically, or using some kind of tool to know how much stack size was initially or is actually allocated for the current running program? I'd also like to know its current figures, if possible.

I'm looking this info for a Windows machine, just in case it makes any difference.

Thanks

Comment: Indeed it is, and that other question covers the answer nicely.

Comment: the other question doesn't answer that at all